# What is the significance of having a common field extension to prove that any isomorphism sends roots to roots of a polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

In the book "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Charles Pinter, page 315, it proved that for a polynomial $a(x)$ over a field $F$, any isomorphism which fixes $F$ sends roots of $a(x)$ to roots of $a(x)$.

The proof is as follows:

Consider $K$ and $K'$ are finite field extensions of $F$, and $K$ and $K'$ have a common extension $E$. If $h:K\rightarrow K'$ is an isomorphism which fixes $F$, and $c \in K$ is a root of a polynomial $a(x) \in F[x]$, then $h(c)$ is also a root of $a(x)$. Hence any isomorphism which fixes $F$ sends roots of $a(x)$ to roots of $a(x)$.

My question is, why is there a need to assume that there exist a common field extension $E$? What is its significance and which part of the proof doesn't work without this assumption?

Comment: This assumption can be dropped without any problem. The proof would be exactly the same without knowing that some common extension exists.

Comment: However, in the next theorem, he proved by first showing that there is a common field extension before applying this lemma. So I thought there might be some significance of having this common extension.

Comment: Lemmas are auxiliary to theorems. Maybe this assumption is meaningful in the context of the theorem (I suppose it is that you can extend $h$ to an automorphism of $E$ under some assumptions). In fact, it is not necessary considering the map $h$ to be an isomorphism of fields. In this lemma, the only important thing is the argument $$a( h ( c )) = h(a(c )) = h(0) = 0$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Even in the context of the theorem, it seems like the common extension is not meaningful... I will state the theorem here:

Let $K$ and $K'$ be finite extension of $F$. Assume $K$ is the splitting field of some polynomial over $F$. If $h:K \rightarrow K'$ is an isomorphism which fixes $F$, then $K=K'$.

Proof: Suppose $K$ and $K'$ are simple extension, say $K = F(a)$ and $K' = F(b)$. Then E = $F(a,b)$ is a common extension of $K$ and $K'$. Since $h$ sends roots of a polynomial to roots of the polynomial, and every element of $K$ is map to an element of $K'$, we have $K' \subseteq K$. Similarly

Comment: Any thoughts about it; is it necessary to have $E$ in the proof?

Comment: Oh, yes, in the theorem existence of $E$ is essential. Otherwise you could abstractly define two distinct splitting fields having $F$ as intersection. Clearly these two would have no common field extension. It may be hard to imagine, but you should construct them outside the algebraic closure. Simply you take one of them, and then a disjoint copy of the first.

Comment: Do you mean like $K'$ is equal to some renaming of elements in $K$ except for those elements in $F$? If this is the case then $K \neq K'$. In the proof $E$ was constructed by $F(a,b)$, which is an assumption, right? Is this the algebraic closure thing that you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to construct two extensions having no common extension. In such  a case the notation $F(a,b)$ makes no sense.